# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when using the EXEC command

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assuming that I have declared the needed variable for the below code, why the first code is returning error while the second code works well. The first one is using the EXEC command while the latter is direct SQL.

Codes which return error
*'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'*

```
Set @SQL='SELECT
    *
FROM
    [myTable]
WHERE 
    [date_field] = ' + @LastDate + '
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Codes that works well

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [myTable]
WHERE 
    [date_field] = @LastDate 
ORDER BY 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)
```

Comment: *Don't* create SQL statements by concatenating strings. That's how SQL Injection attacks and conversion errors happen

Comment: What is `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)` supposed to do?

Comment: BTW `WHERE [date_field] = ' + @LastDate + '` does *NOT* work well. It doesn't work at all because no date field contains the ASCII string `' + @LastDate + '`, ie a space followed by `+` followed by a space then `@LastDate`. Parameters don't need any kind of quoting or escaping. Just use `WHERE [date_filed] = @LastDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn to use parameters and `sp_executesql()`:

```
Set @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM [myTable]
WHERE [date_field] = @LastDate
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)
';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@LastDate date', @LastDate=@LastDate;
```

When running a subquery, you should always use `sp_executesql()`.  In addition to allowing you to pass parameters *in* to a query, it allows you to pass values *out* of the query.  Because it is so powerful, you should simply be in the habit of using it.

I should also note that the `ORDER BY` clause doesn't do anything, because the `date_field` column has only one value.

EDIT:

As for your error, something called `date_field` should be stored using the date/time data types available in the database.  That is why they exist.

You can explicitly convert it for the query.  I would instead recommend that you *fix* the data.

Comment: There is no need to use `sp_executesql` in this case, just write the query and use the parameter

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing it would be using system stored procedure `sp_executesql`.

- 1 It protects you against sql-injection attack
- 2 It also benefits from parameterized execution plans.

---

```
Declare @LastDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
       , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);


Set @SQL= N' SELECT *
             FROM [myTable]
             WHERE [date_field] = @LastDate 
             ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)'

Exec sp_executesql @SQL 
                , N'@LastDate DATETIME'
                , @LastDate
```

Comment: There is no need to use `sp_executesql` in this case, just write the query and use the parameter

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agreed, but usually people post an example to demonstrate the problem they are having with the actual code. So we need to be a bit more generic with the questions asked. If you know what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

you Need to convert The Datetime column to Varchar in String

```
DECLARE @LastDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
       , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

Set @SQL= N' SELECT *
             FROM  [myTable]
             WHERE CONVERT(NVarchar, [date_field],111) = '''++CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@LastDate,111)+'''
             ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: BTW, the error  actually happens on this line : ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date_field]), 0)

Comment: @sicKo Actually error was here   [date_field] = ' + LastDate + '

Comment: There's no reason to convert, quote, escape when you can simply pass the date as a date. String concatenation itself is the bug here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the tip